# Solution for background image when zooming out

Tags: html, css

I've got a PSD template to convert it to HTML. How do I deal with the background food images (highlighted red on the image) when I zoom-out the browser? The total width is 1300px, container is 1000px. What would be the best approach? Do I repeat them? How? What would you do? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by zooming out? Ctrl-- ? Or resizing the browser?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I meant Ctrl--.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/yourimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can go through 2 approaches to get that done...

1. Use 3 different div's to work out.

```html
<div class="left-div"><img src="food_img1.ong"/></div>
<div class="inner-div">Here goes main container</div>
<div class="right-div"><img src="food_img2.ong"/></div>
```

2. Try to use the method given by user Satya above as,

   ```
   html,body{
      background:#333333 url(../img/bg/bg3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
   }
   ```